# get an array of dates from today for datepicker with Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to write a function that returns an array of dates from today till the maximum date, so that I can restrict the date picker selection.  At the moment I have the following:-

```
   datesAfterToday: function (date) {
    var dates = []
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var endDate = new Date(8640000000000000).getFullYear()
    var addDays = function (days) {
      var date = new Date(this.valueOf())
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days)
      return date
    }
    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
      dates.push(currentDate)
      currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1)
    }
    return dates
  }
```

and then I am using Vue.js to mount it as follows :-

```
 mounted () {
   this.allowedDates = this.datesAfterToday
 },
```

however I am only getting an array of objects instead of the proper array.

How can I get the proper array of dates so that I can bind it to the allowdates property.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: You are pushing `Date` objects to array, so you are obtaining array of objects... In what format should those dates be stored in that array? As string? Timestamp?

Comment: I am populating the date-picker, so I guess its string.  However the dates seem to be empty

Comment: So, try `dates.push(currentDate.toString())`. Or other methods as `.toLocaleString()`, `.toLocaleDateString()`, etc.

Comment: tried that but I am getting length 0 and Array(0).  Seems like I have something wrong in the logic

Comment: I think so too. Do you know what year is saved in `endDate` after this statement: `var endDate = new Date(8640000000000000).getFullYear()`?

Comment: Are you using [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker) or something else?

Comment: its 275760.  I think I have to get the date there right?

Comment: @TimHutchison yes vueitfy-datepicker

Comment: Yes. Unless your really need array with hundreds thoussands of dates...

Comment: @WaldemarIce when i do var endDate = new Date(8640000000000000) the browser is hanging on me.

Comment: You're getting an empty array because `new Date(...).getFullYear()` always returns a value, 275760, that is less than `new Date()`, thus your while loop never goes through. But it's pretty unclear what you're trying to do with this part of your code.

Comment: what I want to do is loop through the dates and if it is bigger than today, then add it to the array of dates and then pass it to the datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters `new Date(8640000000000000).getFullYear()` will set `endDate` to the year of that date, which is `275760`. currentDate will be today's date (in milliseconds), which at the time of me writing is `1511272934156`. As you can see currentDate is always greater than endDate, so your while loop never goes to the statements inside.

Another issue is that the date you picked is really far in the future and you're populating an array one day at a time. Your loop will most likely make the page freeze or crash completely. Try picking a date that's more manageable.

For instance, in the snippet below I set `endDate` by first initializing it to today, then setting the year to exactly one year from now. This gives me an array with roughly 365 values.

You can imagine how big this array would be if I used a year that was 273,748 years in the future.

```js
var dates = []
var currentDate = new Date()
var endDate = new Date()

endDate.setFullYear(endDate.getFullYear()+1)

var addDays = function (days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf())
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days)
  return date
}

while (currentDate <= endDate) {
  dates.push(currentDate)
  currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1)
}
    
console.log(dates)
```

With all that being said, it looks like you're actually allowed to pass an object specifying the minimum and maximum values rather than an array.

https://vuetifyjs.com/components/pickers#example-6

```
let d = new Date()                  // today
let d2 = new Date()    
d2.setFullYear(date.getFullYear()+1) // Next year

this.allowedDays = {
    min : d.toISOString().substr(0, 10), // e.g. 2017-11-21
    max : d2.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Khuari, that worked!  Excellent explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker)  For example:

```
<script>
var state = {
    disabled: {
        to: new Date(), // Disable all dates up to specific date
        from: new Date(8640000000000000) // Disable all dates after specific date        
    }
}
</script>

<datepicker :disabled="state.disabled"></datepicker>
```

See [Disabled Dates](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker#disabled-dates) in the documentation.

Comment: I am using the vuefity v-date-picker, and it accepts an array, I tried to follow their examples for example       everyOtherDay: function (date) {
        const [,, day] = date.split('-')
        return parseInt(day, 10) % 2 === 0
      },

Comment: and in the mounted they have this.allowedDates = this.everyOtherDay

Comment: @Johann - I misread your response to me above and thought you were using vuejs-datepicker.  I haven't used vuefity, but I'll leave this answer here as an alternative